# Required auth backend for Django Facebook Python package wasn't found

Tags: python, web-applications, django-authentication, facebook-canvas, pythonanywhere

I've been following this tutorial https://blog.pythonanywhere.com/35/ on 
creating a Facebook Canvas app using PythonAnywhere's Django web app. 
When creating a Django web app, I was asked to choose the Python 
version. I was able to finish the tutorial and it seems to be working 
for Python 2 without any problems, however it's no longer supported so I 
decided to upgrade to Python 3.4 and deleted the old app. I'm using the 
`django_facebook` and installed it with `pip3.4 install --user` on 
`.local` directory as recommended by PythonAnywhere and went thru the 
tutorial again, but when I check the Facebook app, the canvas doesn't 
appear. This is what I find in the PythonAnywhere Error Log:

```
2015-06-26 18:41:30,191 :Required auth backend django_facebook.auth_backends.FacebookBackend wasnt found
2015-06-26 18:43:20,474 :/home/username/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django_facebook/models.py:66: DeprecationWarning: The 'warn' method is deprecated, use 'warning' instead
2015-06-26 18:43:20,474 :  logger.warn('Required auth backend %s wasnt found', required)
2015-06-26 18:43:20,474 :
2015-06-26 18:43:20,473 :/home/username/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django_facebook/models.py:66: DeprecationWarning: The 'warn' method is deprecated, use 'warning' instead
  logger.warn('Required auth backend %s wasnt found', required)

2015-06-26 18:43:20,474 :Required auth backend django_facebook.auth_backends.FacebookBackend wasnt found
```

It says django_facebook.auth_backends.FacebookBackend wasn't found, but 
it's there in my settings.py:

```
"""
Django settings for mysite project.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/
"""

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'                  

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

TEMPLATE_DEBUG = False

AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = 'django_facebook.FacebookProfile'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates').replace('\\','/'),
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                # Insert your TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS here or use this
                # list if you haven't customized them:
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.i18n',
                'django.template.context_processors.media',
                'django.template.context_processors.static',
                'django.template.context_processors.tz',
                'django.core.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'django_facebook.context_processors.facebook',
            ],
        },
    },
]

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
    'django_facebook.context_processors.facebook',
)

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'django_facebook.auth_backends.FacebookBackend',
)

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'django_facebook',
    'jftapp',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    # 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',

    'django_facebook.middleware.FacebookCanvasMiddleWare',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'

# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

FACEBOOK_APP_ID = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'                       
FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'                           
FACEBOOK_CANVAS_PAGE = 'https://apps.facebook.com/%s/' % FACEBOOK_APP_ID
FACEBOOK_SCOPE = ['publish_actions']
```

I've done a web search on this, but it seems like I'm the only who's 
having this issue. I'm early to Django and web programming in general 
and I really want to find out what's causing this error and if there's a 
fix to it.

Comment: just a quick check- the webapp that you created is running on python3.4 and not python2.7 right? and you are not using a virtualenv?

Comment: yes, but I've also tried configuring django manually with virtualenv [link](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/wiki/VirtualEnvForNewerDjango) and here it's much more difficult to check what's going on as there is no error log. I've discovered that django_facebook is a built-in feature on pythonanywhere, but only for python2. It looks like it's the same version as the one on github by martey. The pip package, however doesn't have the canvas_only decorator and I couldn't find any docs for the replacement. I can install from github and it works only when logged out on facebook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [installation instructions](http://django-facebook.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html) mention that it's necessary to add a `AUTH_USER_MODEL` setting and I don't see that in your `settings.py`. You may have missed other steps, but I haven't checked fully.

Comment: It looks like the installation instructions, is for PyPI, which seems to be a completely different module from [github](https://github.com/pythonforfacebook/django-facebook), which is the version I'm using. That's why I got it all mixed up with my `settings.py`. I followed the installation instructions step by step anyway, and there were no more errors this time. Thanks for clearing it up, I got a little confused there.